# Importing audio files for python unit tests

Tags: python, audio, nosetests

how can I import all wav and mp3 files for the purposes of a nosetest?  the files sit in a directory that is up one level from the test files.

Comment: Could you please re-phrase "import all wav and mp3"?  Do you want to open them or what?  How does your code under test normally access them?

Comment: the code normally accesses them via command line and you point to their location.  I dont want to open them, I just want to feed them in as inputs for the purposes of a test.